# How do I extract values of an unknown length out of a string in Java?

Tags: java, string

I'm working on a project where I'm converting from Fortran to Java.  A lot of the changes are straight forward changes.  However, in some cases, I have situations like this:

`IF (___) GOTO number`
will be changed to
`} while (___);`

`MOD(___,___)` will become `___ % ___`

Where `___` represents characters of an unknown length.

How do I go about finding and replacing these strings?

Thanks!

---

Let me be more clear: the project must stand as it is.  I realize there are tools that does this, and I realize that this isn't ideal.  It is what it is unfortunately, so how would I go about doing what I'm asking?

Comment: [Regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)?

Comment: You are working on a project that automatically converts Fortran to Java ?

Comment: To do this properly, you are going to have to write a Fortran parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really probably need to do this via some kind of language-aware parsing of your Fortran code, rather than just by search-and-replace.  You might be able to craft some regex that will cover all your cases, but it's always going to be nasty and error-prone.

I recommend looking at [this project](http://fortran-parser.sourceforge.net/) that provides Fortran parsing tools (in Java!) that will allow you to manipulate a Fortran abstract syntax tree and then code generate Java appropriately, if that is indeed what you are doing.

Comment: +1 for linking a Fortran parser, there's no need to reinvent the wheel when someone's already found all of the pitfalls for you.

Comment: I appreciate the truth in this, however the project must stand as it is.  Can you provide a solution for the question I posed, even though it may not be the ideal way to go about things?

Comment: Look up 'Java regular expressions', or use the link that ajp15243 provided.  That will allow you to write matches over strings, but it's likely to be awful.